# getElementById() returns null even though the element exists

Tags: javascript, html, null, getelementbyid

I'm trying to get the element with getElementById(), but it returns null even though the element exists. What am I doing wrong?

```
<html>
<head> 
    <title>blah</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert(document.getElementById("abc"));
    </script>
</head> 
<body>
    <div id="abc">

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This question has been closed and redirected to an answer that explicitly involves jQuery, but this question doesn't involve jQuery. I think this question was wrongly closed. It either needs to be reopened OR redirected instead to a different question, if one exists, that does not use jQuery.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You have to put this in a `document` `load` event. The DOM hasn't gotten to `abc` by the time the script is executed.

Comment: Putting the script at the bottom is probably easier for starters.

Comment: Ah, Thank you! Always thought the script was run after the html was loaded.

Comment: Please note that you have to wait like 10 minutes before being able to accept.

Comment: im starter in javascript and I think this answer needs an example of that document load hehe

Comment: Also, it is helpful to add that another reason for this, is to verify that the path to the component id is good, not only the form id, also the parent of the form if it has one (for example an accordeon), and then the component, verify always this.

Comment: window.onload works, instead of document.onload. ^_^

Answer (score 52):

Your script runs before the DOM has been loaded.  To fix this you can place your code in the `window.onload` function like so:

```
window.onload = function() {
    alert(document.getElementById("abc"));
};
```

An alternative is to place your `script` right before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: "Right before /BODY" may confuse beginners. The requirement is to place the SCRIPT after the HTML element that the script needs to reference. The distance to /BODY is not relevant.

Comment: another thing to note. If you have a window.onload that follows another window onload **from top-to-bottom on the document**, the second window onload will override the content of the first window.onload. For example, if you tried setting a **<div>s** background color inside the first window.onload using a JS handle like so: `document.getElementById('div01').style.background =  'blue';` and had the same handle inside the second window.onload but set to 'black', your div's background color would be black not blue. Order in the DOM matters.

Comment: Great answer! Simple and including the working example!

Answer (score 11):

If you don't want to attach to the load event then simply put your script at the bottom of the body, so it will execute at the end-

```
<html>
<head> 
    <title>blah</title>    
</head> 
<body>
    <div id="abc">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert(document.getElementById("abc"));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is because the script runs before the page has rendered.

For proof add this attribute to the body tag:

```
<body onload="alert(document.getElementById('abc'));" >
```

Answer (score 1):

But it doesn't exist, not at that point in the HTML. HTML documents are parsed top-to-bottom, just like programs run. The best solution is just to put your script tag at the bottom of the page. You could also attach your JavaScript to the onload event.