# document not defined error javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, recursion, browser

I'm learning javascript and have created some HTML within my javascript file so as to test a simple function that takes in nodes as parameters.  I keep getting a 'document not defined' error. What do I need to do within my JS file/code to define the document?

I already tried things listed here:
[ReferenceError: document is not defined (in plain JavaScript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24647839/referenceerror-document-is-not-defined-in-plain-javascript)

```
   var div1 = document.createElement("div");
var text1 = document.createTextNode('<div id="one">Some<span>node <em>contents</em> for</span>comparison</div>');
div1.appendChild(text1);
document.body.appendChild(div1);

var div2 = document.createElement("div");
var text2 = document.createTextNode('<div id="two">Some<span>node contents for</span>comparison</div>');
div2.appendChild(text2);
document.body.appendChild(div2);


var div3 = document.createElement("div");
var text3 = document.createTextNode('<div id="one">Some<span>node <strong>contents</strong> for</span>comparison</div>');
div3.appendChild(text3);
document.body.appendChild(div3);

var div4 = document.createElement("div");
var text4 = document.createTextNode('<div id="four">Some<span>node <em>contents</em> for</span>comparison</div>');
div4.appendChild(text4);
document.body.appendChild(div4);



function nodeEquivalence(node1, node2) {
    var equal = false;
    if (node1.innerHTML === node2.innerHTML) {
        if (node1.tagName === node2.tagName) {
            if (node1.type === node2.type) {
                equal = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return equal;
}

console.log(nodeEquivalence(div1, div4));
```

Comment: document is a global, so the fact that it's not defined leads me to ask, which browser are you testing this on?

Comment: Thanks for your time. I'm testing this on chrome dev tools as well as in my sublime console... It's javascript only.

Comment: so, no DOM - hence no document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use innerHTML. Use **createTextNode** or **textContent**.

Create HTML element the right way:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
var text = document.createTextNode("some text");
div.appendChild(text);
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Your function is too complicated to compare to HTML nodes. This function

```
function nodeEquivalence(node1, node2) {
    var equal = false;
    if (node1.innerHTML === node2.innerHTML) {
        if (node1.tagName === node2.tagName) {
            if (node1.type === node2.type) {
                equal = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return equal;
}
```

is much easier.