# add className on scroll in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, event-listener

I'm trying to add a `className` on scroll. I keep getting a

> document is undefined

**edit:** I found out I was getting the error from the typo. When I define `document.getElementsByClassName("main-nav").scrollTop` nothing comes up in the `console`. As well as the page does not get affected.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  windowScroll();
};

function windowScroll() {
  if (document.getElementsByClassName("main-nav").scrollTop > 50 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("main-nav").className = "test";
  } else {
    document.getElementsByClassName("main-nav").className = "";
  }
}
```

CSS is

```css
.test {
  background: pink
}
```

I'm not necessarily looking for the answer, I just want guidance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24647839/referenceerror-document-is-not-defined-in-plain-javascript

Comment: Since you choose `getElementsByClassName` so it will get all class names but you want one of them, I suggest you to use jquery it will be much easier than JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 problems:

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array of `HTMLCollection` and it has no property `scrollTop`. You probably want the first item so the code shoul be `document.getElementsByClassName("main-nav")[0]` (or `document.querySelector(".main-nav")`)

But if you try it, you will get an error:

> Cannot read property 'scrollTop' of undefined

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  windowScroll();
};

function windowScroll() {
  if (document.getElementsByClassName("main-nav").scrollTop > 50 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("main-nav").className = "test";
  } else {
    document.getElementsByClassName("main-nav").className = "";
  }
}
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 150%;
}

.test {
  background: pink
}
```

```html
<div class="main-nav"></div>
```

The reason is that you override the `class` attribute of `.main-nav` by this assignment:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("main-nav").className = "";
```

In this line you set the `class` attribute to empty string. You probably want to add / remove the test call but keeping the `main-nav` class.

There are 2 things you can do:

1. Set the `id` attribute to `main-nav` instead of the `class` attribute, then use `document.getElementById` method.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  windowScroll();
};

function windowScroll() {
  if (document.getElementById("main-nav").scrollTop > 50 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50) {
    document.getElementById("main-nav").className = "test";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("main-nav").className = "";
  }
}
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 150%;
}

#main-nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.test {
  background: pink
}
```

```html
<div id="main-nav">Main Nav</div>
```

2. Toggle only the `test` class using `classList.toggle`.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  windowScroll();
};

function windowScroll() {
  if (document.getElementsByClassName("main-nav")[0].scrollTop > 50 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("main-nav")[0].classList.add("test");
  } else {
    document.getElementsByClassName("main-nav")[0].classList.remove("test");
  }
}
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 150%;
}

.main-nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.test {
  background: pink
}
```

```html
<div class="main-nav">Main Nav</div>
```

---

The final approach with some optimisations:

```js
var mainNav = document.querySelector('.main-nav');

window.onscroll = function() {
  windowScroll();
};

function windowScroll() {
    mainNav.classList.toggle("test", mainNav.scrollTop > 50 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50);
}
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 150%;
}

.main-nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.test {
  background: pink
}
```

```html
<div class="main-nav">Main Nav</div>
```

The changes:

1. Store the `.main-nav` element on the global context (the `window` object). It will not change so you don't need to find it in any scroll.
2. Use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector#Syntax) so you will get a single DOM element, not collection.
3. Use [`classList.toggle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Examples) to toggle the class by condition.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm fairly new at javascript and basically looked at W3 school and tried to use their example with mine without knowing how everyone works with conjunction with each other. Your help + w3 schools made this possible for me. Thank you again.

Comment: I glad I could help :) Good luck!

Comment: @MoshFeu - Wondered why you have also set `document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50`?

Comment: TBH, I don't remember but probably I didn't change this part from the OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your console.log is that you're trying to pull the scrollTop for an HTML Collection (a collection of elements in your page) of 1 or more divs - therefore it can't check for the scrollTop as the console.log as it doesn't actually have that property.

Assuming you only have one element with the "main-nav" class (or there is a particular element with this class that you wish to apply it to), you would be better off using one of the following: `document.getElementsByClassName("main-nav")[0]` or `document.getElementById("main-nav")` (the latter would require you to create a main-nav id rather than a class).

For the first one, however, using className reassigns the class name rather than adding to that particular div, therefore you can use `document.getElementsByClassName("main-nav")[0].classList.add("test")` (and `remove` instead of `add` if it does not match your criteria).

If there is more than one element with the "main-nav" class, you can still use the first option I suggested - only you would need to wrap it around in a for loop and replace the 0 with your variable of choice.

```
for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName("main-nav").length; i++) {
  //your code here using document.getElementsByClassName("main-nav")[i]
}
```