# couldn't get element using document.querySelector

Tags: javascript, dom

I tried accessing my image source with *document.querySelector* but unfortunately it throws an error **ReferenceError: document is not defined**

**HTML code :**

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Refresh !</h1>

    <div class="dice">
      <p>Player 1</p>
      <img src="images/dice1.png" alt="diceimage">
    </div>

    <div class="dice">
      <p>Player 2</p>
      <img src="images/dice1.png" alt="diceimage">
    </div>

  </div>

  <script src="index.js" charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
```

**JavaScript code:**

```
//player1
var randomNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
var randomImage1 = "images/"+"dice"+randomNumber1+".png";

document.querySelectorAll("img")[0].setAttribute("src",randomImage1);

//player2
var randomNumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
var randomImage2 = "images/"+"dice"+randomNumber2+".png";

document.querySelectorAll("img")[1].setAttribute("src",randomImage2);


//condition
if (randomNumber1 > randomNumber2) {
    document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = "Player 1 Wins";
} else if (randomNumber1 < randomNumber2){
    document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = "Player 2 Wins";
} else {
    document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = "Draw";
}
```

**Error :**

> document.querySelectorAll("img")[0].setAttribute("src",randomImage1);
> ^
>
> ReferenceError: document is not defined
> at Object. (G:\WebDevelopmentFolder\GITHUB\DiceGame\index.js:5:1)
>
> ?[90m    at Module._compile
> (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)?[39m ?[90m    at
> Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:1
> 0)?[39m ?[90m    at Module.load
> (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)?[39m ?[90m    at
> Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)?[39m
> ?[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain]
> (internal/modules/run_ma in.js:72:12)?[39m ?[90m    at
> internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47?[39m

Comment: Sounds like your script is running in Node, not in the browser...

Comment: The code work perfectly in browser

Comment: Are you using nextJs ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReferenceError: document is not defined (in plain JavaScript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24647839/referenceerror-document-is-not-defined-in-plain-javascript)

Comment: @PawanSharma Nope

Comment: @angel.bonev I did check that link before but couldn't solve my issue

Comment: @CertainPerformance Is there a way to run this external JS script ?

Comment: Open the HTML instead of trying to run the JS with Node