# Error while using flowbite with nextJS and typescript

Tags: typescript, next.js, tailwind-css

I installed tailwind and flowbite to a NextJS project. As I did `import  "flowbite"` in `_app.tsx`, I get the following error.

```
ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at Object.366 (D:\shopflo\next-tailwind-typescript-starter\node_modules\flowbite\dist\flowbite.js:35:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\shopflo\next-tailwind-typescript-starter\node_modules\flowbite\dist\flowbite.js:496:41)
    at D:\shopflo\next-tailwind-typescript-starter\node_modules\flowbite\dist\flowbite.js:509:17
    at D:\shopflo\next-tailwind-typescript-starter\node_modules\flowbite\dist\flowbite.js:2631:3
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\shopflo\next-tailwind-typescript-starter\node_modules\flowbite\dist\flowbite.js:2633:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
error - ReferenceError: document is not defined
ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at Object.366 (D:\shopflo\next-tailwind-typescript-starter\node_modules\flowbite\dist\flowbite.js:35:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\shopflo\next-tailwind-typescript-starter\node_modules\flowbite\dist\flowbite.js:496:41)
    at D:\shopflo\next-tailwind-typescript-starter\node_modules\flowbite\dist\flowbite.js:509:17
    at D:\shopflo\next-tailwind-typescript-starter\node_modules\flowbite\dist\flowbite.js:2631:3
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\shopflo\next-tailwind-typescript-starter\node_modules\flowbite\dist\flowbite.js:2633:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
```

`document is not defined`  gives a clue that javascript is creating problems. Please help with this. In my tsconfig.json  `allowJS:true` is set then why is this creating problems?

Comment: As next.js is server-side-rendered no document or window (browser only) are present.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24647839/referenceerror-document-is-not-defined-in-plain-javascript

Comment: I'm facing same issue now. Did you later find your way around it? If yes, how?

Comment: I used headless-ui instead.

Answer (score 1):

from the docs, Flowbite is currently working on a standalone library for compatibility with React frameworks such as NextJS [check here](https://flowbite.com/docs/getting-started/react/#flowbite-components)

Answer (score 1):

This work fine for me. Every flowbite component have a init function to make it interactive.

```js
import { initAccordions } from "flowbite";

  useEffect(() => {
    initAccordions();
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

if you are using remix js just add `import 'flowbite'` in entry.client.tsx file