# Playing audio via an iframe using javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe, frame

I have the following code in `abc.jsp`

```
 <% 
 out.write("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"scripts/test.js\"></script>");
 out.write("Here is filename"+sfl);
 out.write(""
        + "<input type=\"button\" id=\"playBt\" value=\"Play Now\" onClick=\"playSound()\" >"
        + "<audio id=\"sound\" preload=\"auto\">"
        + "<source src=\"music.ogg\" type=\"audio/ogg\" />"
        + "<source src=\"music.mp3\" type=\"audio/mpeg\" />"
        + "Your browser does not support the audio element."
        + "</audio>"
      );
out.write("");
%>
```

Then content above was brought in in a frame in `index.jsp`

```
 <iframe id='bgframe' style='display:compact;' src='abc.jsp' width="400" height="200"></iframe>
```

This JavaScript function is now used - `test.js`

```
function playSound() {  
  var frameRef = document.getElementById('bgframe');
  var sound = frameRef.contentWindow.document.getElementById'sound');
  //var sound = frameRef.contentDocument.document.getElementById('sound');
  sound.play();
}
```

The problem is that, the sound does not play when I click on play button.
On the JavaScript console, the system returns null as value of `frameRef`.
Also, I get the following error depending on whether I use `contentDocument` or `contentWindow`.

> `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contentDocument'`
>   `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contentWindow'`

I've implemented different solutions but the uncaught typedef error remains.

Please what am I doing wrong here and how can I fix it?  Why can't I access elements on frame `id=bgframe`?

Answer (score 1):

You are including your `test.js` in `abc.jsp`, **not** in `index.jsp` so you don't need to refer to iframe, because the script is already running inside it. 
You only need to make some changes in `playSound()` function:

```
function playSound() {  
  var sound = document.getElementById('sound');
  //do your stuff here
  //line below should make your script alert 'auto' in your case
  alert(sound.preload); 
}
```

Comment: test.js is an external javascript.  It is not included in abc.jsp.  Also, what I intend to do is to be able to play this sound on index.jsp via a frame.  When I tested it without frame, everything worked fine, but I need it played via a frame embeded in index.jsp.

Comment: The error points specifically to this line:      var sound = frameRef.contentWindow.document.getElementById'sound'); where a null is returned.

Comment: You are including test.js in the second line of abc.jsp `out.write("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"scripts/test.js\"></script>");`. Your test.js is running in the iframe (in abc.js), not directly in index.jsp. I don't think you understand what are you doing :) First check if my code works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  What you see up here is a snipped of a code that I am trying to implement in a much bigger project.  The reason you see that I am calling abc.jsp in index.jsp via an iframe is that, at the end of the day, my code may run on a different domain, but I will only give the iframe line of code to clients to put on their web site.  In that way, I am letting my test.js to be included in abc.jsp so that only one line of code loads both my javascript and jsp. I don't want to give the client many lines of code. I just found a solution.

Comment: This link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371047/getelementbyid-returns-null-even-though-the-element-exists?rq=1)  gave me some insight. It was there I found out that I was calling playSound() before the DOM is fully loaded. Now it is working after I placed my code in window.onload = function(){...