# I don't know why this canvas is null

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

So I've been looking at a couple of examples of how to fill a canvas with some other image, and as soon as I rearrange the code slightly they stop working.  I'm noticing some behavior on canvases that doesn't make sense compared to other types of javascript variables, and I'd like to know what's going on.  for instance, if I do something like this...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var someVar = "This variable has been set";

            function aFunction(){
                alert(someVar);
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="aFunction()">
        <canvas id="aCanvas" height="100" width="100"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

...I get a pop-up saying "This variable has been set", which is what I would expect, but if I do something like this...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var aCanvas = document.getElementById("aCanvas");
            var context;

            function aFunction(){
                try{
                    context = aCanvas.getContext("2d");
                    alert("it worked");
                }
                catch(err){
                    alert(err);
                }
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="aFunction()">
        <canvas id="aCanvas" height="100" width="100"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

...I get an alert with the message "TypeError:  aCanvas is undefined"

And yet, if I try to define the canvas the same way within the try itself...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var aCanvas;
            var context;

            function aFunction(){
                try{
                    aCanvas = document.getElementById("aCanvas");
                    context = aCanvas.getContext("2d");
                    alert("it worked");
                }
                catch(err){
                    alert(err);
                }
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="aFunction()">
        <canvas id="aCanvas" height="100" width="100"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

I get the message "it worked"

So if I want to initialze a global variable as a string or something simple, I can then reference it in functions.  If I try to initialize a global variable as a canvas, my functions go on to think that it is null.  Why is that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [getElementById() returns null even though the element exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371047/getelementbyid-returns-null-even-though-the-element-exists)

Comment: before getting an element by id (or with any method) you must make sure that the DOM was loaded. Personnaly i wrap all my code inside a function that i call on page load.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the time before 'onload' runs, when the HTML is first being parsed and it runs your script, there are no elements in the document. It hasn't reached the `<body`> tag yet, so the "document" is empty. This is still an opportune time to initialize Javascript-only variables and perhaps some other things, but really a large part of your starting code should occur inside of 'onLoad'.

In short: Your code's success very much depends on *when* you call `getElementById`, not where the `var aCanvas` statement is. Hope that helps your understanding.