# Update span from code behind ie

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, ext.net

I am using the following back-end c# code to see if I need to update the text inside a `span`.

c#:

```
if (status1.InnerHtml != temp1)
        {
            status1.InnerHtml = temp1;
            status1.Update();
        }
```

html:

```
<span runat="server" id="status1">Status 1</span>
```

This works fine in chrome and firefox, but it has issues in **ie**.

Visually, this is what happens (only in ie):

first time:[image]

second time:[image]

**Possible Source of Error**

I noticed that `status1.InnerHtml` always returns `Status 1`; as in it never changes. This leads me to believe that this is why it is creating a second element.

This means that I need to find a way to get the the current value of the `span`, using something besides `InnerHtml` (`runat="server"` was supposed to solve this issue).

Looking at the code in ie, on initial load, it is displayed properly. However, the second time I execute the code,

it turns

```
<ext.net.direct.update id="status1"/>
  <span id="status1">
    Text - Transfer completed
</ext.net.direct.update/>
```

(Note: the closing span tag was removed)

into

```
<span id="el_status1_container">
  <span id="status1">
    Text - Transfer completed
    <span id="status1">
      Text - Transfer completed
</ext.net.direct.update/>
```

(Note: `<ext.net.direct.update id="status1"/>` gets removed from the code, an element with a duplicate ID is inserted)

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated! Thank you

Comment: I could investigate, if you provide a runnable test case to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @DaniilVeriga thank you for the offer but I already found an alternative answer; see below.

Comment: Yes, I saw, but you wrote "This is a workaround, so if anyone has a better answer, please share!".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with was to make a button that when clicked loads the statuses. Using javascript, I clicked the button when it is generated with this code found from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371047/getelementbyid-returns-null-even-though-the-element-exists).

```
function initialload() {
    if (document.getElementById('Label1')) {
        document.getElementById("Label1").click();
    } else {
        setTimeout(initialload, 15);
}
```

This works because it turns out `ie` was ignoring the initial span (weird, but hey, it's ie) and using the second one to update it.

This is a workaround, so if anyone has a better answer, please share!