# onload event not working

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

There are so many posts for this. I have gone through all of those, yet no luck. I'm struggling for so long (Onload event is not working ). I dint find any solution.

I have tried..
1.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('pdfcontent').onload = function() {
   alert("working");
}

</script>
</head>
<body >
<div id="loadingpdf">Loading pdf</div>
<iframe src="http://prodevapp.com/ArmyPublicRelation/pdf/royalthaiarmynews/news_20141103173559.pdf" id="pdfcontent" />
</body>
</html>
```

2.

```
$.ajaxSetup(
            {
                cache: false,
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $('object').hide();
                    $('#loadingpdf').show();
                },
                complete: function() {
                    $('#loadingpdf').hide();
                    $('object').show();
                },
                success: function() {
                    $('#loadingpdf').hide();
                    $('object').show();
                }
            });
            var $container = $('object');
            $container.load(function(){
        alert("Image loaded.");});
```

3.

```
         <body >
    <script>
function my_code(){
alert(" working");
}
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");    
iframe.src = "http://prodevapp.com/ArmyPublicRelation/pdf/royalthaiarmynews/news_20141103173559.pdf";
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
iframe.onload=my_code;
</script>
</body>
```

4.

```
$("iframe").on('load', function() {
  alert('Image Loaded'); 
}).each(function() {
  if(this.complete) $(this).load();
});  //this worked one time but later it doesn't work it seems some cache problem.
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Fix what? You've not asked an actual question. All there is is 4 snippets of seemingly disjointed code.

Comment: Once pdf is loaded I need to alert an message. I have tried 4 ways to achieve this but dint work

Answer (score 0):

1. Duplicate of [getElementById() returns null even though the element exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371047/getelementbyid-returns-null-even-though-the-element-exists) and you are also missing the end tag for the `<iframe>`.
2. You are using an iframe, not Ajax, so watching for Ajax things won't work
3. You try to use the `iframe` variable before you assign a value to it.

   - After editing it - you try to use a function before it has been defined. While functions are hoisted, they aren't hoisted from later scripts.
   - After editing it again - [it works](http://jsbin.com/duxapudoce/2/edit?html,output).
4. Also a duplicate of [getElementById() returns null even though the element exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371047/getelementbyid-returns-null-even-though-the-element-exists)

Comment: Shall i know in 1. where am missing the end tag for <iframe> `<iframe src="http://prodevapp.com/ArmyPublicRelation/pdf/royalthaiarmynews/news_20141103173559.pdf" id="pdfcontent" />` and for 3. I changed my code and tried but no luck i have updated my post .

Comment: @VidhyaRaju — You see where you don't have `</iframe>`? That's where you are missing the end tag.

Comment: but am using `/>` at the end.

Comment: I tried with some code change in 3 as you mentioned but still problem exists. I have updated.

Comment: @VidhyaRaju — Using `/>` at the end is not the same as putting an end tag. It just means you're addicted to XML. HTML is not XML.

Comment: The latest version of your 3rd code sample works: http://jsbin.com/duxapudoce/2/edit?html,output

Comment: Can you pls have a look at this [quote](http://quotequads.co.in/erase.php). I tried the same code, but it doesn't work. Why is it so?

Comment: In my sys, I tried in both mozilla and chrome it doesn't work. Now I tried from other system it works fine. What would be problem?

Answer (score 0):

You might find help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30005/how-do-i-fire-an-event-when-a-iframe-has-finished-loading-in-jquery)

The selected answer on this thread, interestingly, suggests you cant track a pdf load.