# How to create a link based on textbox value?

Tags: javascript, html, onchange, getelementbyid, onkeyup

I'm trying to change the href of my link based on whats in the textbox with `id="serie"`. As you can see, Firefox tells me that `el` is null. What did go wrong here?

(Upper part is Page, Middle part the debug-console and the lower part is my source code)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var el = document.getElementById('serie');
            var lnk = document.getElementById('link');
            el.onchange = el.onkeyup = function() {lnk.href = "http://bs.infinibrain.net/" + userInput + ".xml";};
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Anleitung</h1>
        1. <a href="index.xml" target="_blank">Hier</a> die id eurer Serie suchen (Leider sind noch nicht alle aufgelistet)<br/>
        2. dann id hier eingeben: <input id="serie" /><br/>
        3. und <a href="#" id="link">hier</a> die links raussuchen <br/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you make a jsFiddle?

Comment: Will you post your code here instead of image.

Comment: jsfiddle is down for me :(

Comment: the problem is that your javascript code is running before your html page is fully loaded, if you move the script in the lower part of the body it will works ;-)

Comment: None of the answers works...

Comment: die Daten in dem XML-File und dieses bs sehen verdächtig nach bs.to aus ... ;)

Comment: Did you search on SO? This is the topic of a dozen or more questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [getElementById() returns null even though the element exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371047/getelementbyid-returns-null-even-though-the-element-exists)

Comment: @roeb: Ich habe eine Kopie der BS Link-Datenbank, SC ist ja gerade ausgeblendet

Comment: Or see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access the `element` even before its loaded. Place your `script` at the end of your `body`.

```
    <html>
    <body>
        <h1>Anleitung</h1>
        1. <a href="index.xml" target="_blank">Hier</a> die id eurer Serie suchen (Leider sind noch nicht alle aufgelistet)<br/>
        2. dann id hier eingeben: <input id="serie" /><br/>
        3. und <a href="#" id="link">hier</a> die links raussuchen <br/>
        <script>
            var el = document.getElementById('serie');
            var lnk = document.getElementById('link');
            el.onchange = el.onkeyup = function() {lnk.href = "http://bs.infinibrain.net/" + userInput + ".xml";};
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also you didnot define `userInput`, it should be `el.value`:

```
lnk.href = "http://bs.infinibrain.net/" + el.value + ".xml";
```

Comment: @Paedow I updated my answer. Works fine See [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Lypn61tr/).

Answer (score 3):

You need use [`window.onload`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp), because your script runs before the DOM has been loaded

```
window.onload = function () {
   // your code 
}
```

or put script before `</body>`

[`Example`](http://jsfiddle.net/j7yep2zt/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Your script is being evaluated before the page is loaded, which means that the html DOM is not yet available. What you need to do is add you script in the `load` event of the window. This event is triggered when the page is fully loaded:

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener("load", function () {
        var el = document.getElementById('serie');
        var lnk = document.getElementById('link');
        el.onchange = el.onkeyup = function() {lnk.href = "http://bs.infinibrain.net/" + userInput + ".xml";};
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It's still not working. I put this before </body> and in the <head>, but none of those work

Answer (score 0):

You need to use document [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) or `window.onload`.

```
window.onload = function() {}
```

**OR**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {})
```

Answer (score 0):

`userInput` variable is undefined.

And move your script below your html content. It will be like this

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>Anleitung</h1>
    1. <a href="index.xml" target="_blank">Hier</a> die id eurer Serie suchen (Leider sind noch nicht alle aufgelistet)<br/>
    2. dann id hier eingeben: <input id="serie" /><br/>
    3. und <a href="#" id="link">hier</a> die links raussuchen <br/>

<script>
var el = document.getElementById('serie');
var lnk = document.getElementById('link');
el.onchange = function() {
  userInput = el.value;
  lnk.href = "http://bs.infinibrain.net/" + userInput + ".xml";};
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

BTW changing question after answers are given is not allowed.

Comment: Just changed the title to a more appropriate one