# Uncaught TypeError: this.getElementById is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, typeerror

I am making a Vanilla Javascript Component for a Top Navigation Bar. I am trying to add an "active" class to a certain element based upon a component argument. The code is attached below, I will explain further.

```
class navbarC extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  connectedCallback(){
    const page = this.getAttribute('page');
    console.log(page) //Returns "home"
    console.log(typeof page) //Returns "string"
    this.getElementById(page).classList.add("active");
    this.render()
  }
  render(){
    this.innerHTML=`
<style>
  .nav-pills .nav-item {
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.nav-pills .nav-item:last-child { 
    margin-right: 0px;
}

.nav-pills .nav-item .nav-link.active {
    background-color: #e92121;
    color: #fff; 
    border-radius: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
  
.nav-pills .nav-item .nav-link:hover {
    background-color: #c91010; 
    color: #fff; 
    border-radius: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.nav-pills .nav-item .nav-link:not(active) {
    color: #000000; 
}
</style>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style="background-color: #fff;">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand px-3" href="#"> 
      <img src="assets/logo2.png" width="30" height="30" alt="Random Thingy">
      Random Thingy
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbar"
      aria-controls="navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/index.html" id="home">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/menu.html" id="menu">Menu</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/reservation.html" id="reservations">Reservations</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/reviews.html" id="reviews">Reviews</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/aboutus.html" id="about-us">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/checkout.html" id="checkout">Checkout</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>`
  }
}
customElements.define("navbar-c",navbarC)
```

The problem I am having here is that I am trying to reference and alter HTML code to the render() function by adding a class to an element with the certain id. `this.getElementById(page).classList.add("active");` <-- This is the code I use to attempt to add a class to an element with a certain id, however I suspect that it it not referencing the code I want to manipulate. This line gives me the error, `Uncaught TypeError: this.getElementById is not a function at navbarC.connectedCallback`.

I tried have tried putting this code into the the constructor() function and have googled in search of how to reference the HTML code inside the element. I am new the JS, so this might be a trivial fix I am not used to.

Comment: `getElementById` is only available on the document, not the element. Try `this.ownerDocument.getElementById`.

Comment: Doing that has worked in addressing the element, however, after console logging the element, it shows that the element is null. I am not sure how that works because the code is written right there in the document.

Comment: What is null? I just tried the code and it looks like it works. What are you logging, where, and when?

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')" is the exact error. I am using the regular Chrome inspect console, and run the application to VS Code's Live Server Extension.

Comment: Do you have an element with `id="home"`? Because it sounds like you are trying to get an element that doesn't exists, and then you get null.

Comment: "<a class="nav-link" href="/index.html" id="home">Home</a>" I do, I have tried googling it, and found this. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371047/getelementbyid-returns-null-even-though-the-element-exists 

I couldn't exact interpret that situation and how to implement it in my code.

Comment: Now I see. You are trying to get the element with id = home before you have added it to the document. You must call render to insert the element before you try to get it. See my updated answer.

Comment: For you next question: Try to supply a minimal example. For example no CSS if the question isn't about CSS. I didn't see you element with `id="home"` at first glance, making it harder for me to understand your code. See my answer for an example. I see that you have accepted the answer but not voted on it, but that might be because you haven't got enough reputation yet. I upvoted your question so you got some. Welcome to Stackoverflow! Happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) is a method on the Document interface.

You should be able to get the document of the element by using [ownerDocument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/ownerDocument).

Change the code from

```
this.getElementById(page)
```

to

```
this.ownerDocument.getElementById(page)
```

The second problem it that you try to get the element with id = home before you have added it. Move the call to `this.render()` to before you try to access it, and it works.

Like this:

```js
class navbarC extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  connectedCallback() {
    const page = this.getAttribute('page');
    console.log(page); //Returns "home"
    console.log(typeof page); //Returns "string"
    this.render();
    this.ownerDocument.getElementById(page).classList.add('active');
  }
  render() {
    this.innerHTML = `<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/index.html" id="home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/menu.html" id="menu">Menu</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>`;
  }
}

customElements.define('navbar-c', navbarC);
```

```html
<navbar-c page="home"></navbar-c>
```